# Highchart flags goes out when range selector is set to entire size

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

As you can see here: [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/vzbng5r4/)

The main problem is when range selector is set to full size, we can see only two lines, without flags at the left side. If range selector is set to smaller range and you drag it to left side, it seems like everything is ok with flags. But if a little part of line will be at chart, everything is going wrong.

I tried to sort series in ascending order, but it didn't make any results.

Still have no clue what's wrong.

Highchart setup:

```
    {

            title: {
                text: 'Problem with flags'
            },
            chart: {
                  zoomType: 'x',
                },
                yAxis: {
                  min: 0,
                  startOnTick: false
                },
              xAxis: {
                  type: 'datetime',
                  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    millisecond: '%H:%M',
                    second: '%H:%M',
                    minute: '%H:%M',
                    hour: '%H:%M',
                    day: '%e. %b',
                    week: '%e. %b',
                    month: '%b \'%y',
                    year: '%Y'
                  },
                  showEmpty: true
                },
                credits: {
                  enabled: false
                },
                lang: {
                  rangeSelectorZoom: ''
                },
            rangeSelector: {
                  allButtonsEnabled: false,
                  inputEnabled: false,
                  buttonTheme: {
                    visibility: 'hidden'
                  },
                  labelStyle: {
                    display: 'none'
                  }
                },
                        plotOptions: {
                  series: {
                    turboThreshold: 0
                  }
                },
                        legend: {
                  enabled: true
                },
            series: SERIES ARE AT FIDDLE
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, you should set xAxis.ordinal field to false, [here is link](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal)